# Jquery slider is not working when hosted on server but working perfect in local. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider, banner

Jquery slider is not working when hosted on server but working perfect in local. Why? i uploaded all the source content to my website.
here is the hosted link of my website
navarangtravels.com/jq/jq

Kindly point the error

```
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>

        <!-- DC Dream Accordion CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dream-accordion.css" />
        <!-- DC Javascript Library -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="dcodes/jquery.min.js"></script><!-- jQuery Library (do not call twice on same page) -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="dcodes/jquery.easing.js"></script><!-- jQuery Easing (do not call twice on same page) -->
        <!-- DC Dream Accordion JS -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/froogaloop.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.transform-0.9.3.min.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.getimagedata.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dream-accordion.js"></script>
        <!-- DC Dream Accordion Settings -->
        <script type="text/javascript">

            // SETTINGS
            var as_settings = {
                /* visibleItems: less of equal to total items in acordion  */
                visibleItems:5,
                /* slideshowOn; true, false */
                slideshowOn: true,
                /* useGlobalDelay; true, false (use same timer delay for all slides, if false you NEED to set individual delays for all slides) */
                useGlobalDelay: true,
                /* slideshowDelay; slideshow delay, in miliseconds (2500 = 2.5 seconds) */
                slideshowDelay: 2500,
                /* randomPlay; true, false (play slides in normal or random order or to be more accurate, if true - mixes slide order on the beginning to simulate random) */
                randomPlay: false,
                /* includeVideoInSlideshow; autoplay video if exist in slide and on video finish continue with next slide (true/false) */
                includeVideoInSlideshow: false,
                /* openOnRollover; true, false (open slides on rollover or click) */
                openOnRollover: true,
                /* useScroll; true, false */
                useScroll: true,
                /* scrollDraggerOverColor; scroll dragger color on mouse over */
                scrollDraggerOverColor: '#658',
                /* useControls; true/false */
                useControls: true,
                /* openSlideNum; open slide on begining, enter -1 for none, 0 = first, 1 = second, 2 = third... etc. */
                openSlideNum: 0,
                /* transitionTime: transition time for slide in miliseconds */
                transitionTime: 1000,
                /* transitionEase: transition ease for slide, (some eases may possibly not work correctly), check eases here: http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/ */
                transitionEase: 'easeOutQuint'
            };

            jQuery(window).load(function() {
                jQuery.noConflict();
                jQuery.accordionSlider('#sliderWrapper', as_settings);
                as_settings = null;

                //after div holder (#gmap_canvas) for google map is ready in the dom, otherwise we get an error in ie coming from google maps.
                //google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
                initializeGmap();
            });

            /*
            https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference
            google map example
            */

            var gmap;
            function initializeGmap() {
                var myOptions = {
                  zoom: 8,
                  center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.856614, 2.3522219), // google map location to show
                  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                gmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_canvas'),
                    myOptions);
            }

        </script>
        </head>

        <body>

<!-- DC Dream Accordion Start -->
<div style="width:980px; margin:0 auto; padding:10px; position:relative;"> <!-- define slider container width (strict enforce) -->
          <div id="sliderWrapper">
    <div class="sliderCointainer">
              <div class="sliderHolder"> 
        <!-- Slide 1 -->
        <div class='slideDiv' data-width='500' data-content='' data-link='http://www.google.com' data-target='_blank' data-delay='3000'> <img class='stack_img' src='images/pamban.jpg' width='500' height='333' alt='' />
                  <p data-title='title' class="-90,bl,10,10" data-background-color="rgba(51,51,51, 0.6)" data-color="#ffffff">Rameswaram</p>
                  <p data-title='caption' class="50,200" data-background-color="rgba(51,51,51, 0.6)" data-color="#ffffff">The India's Holiest Place</p>
                  <p data-title='caption' class="50,250" data-background-color="rgba(51,51,51, 0.3)" data-color="#ffffff"> <a style="text-decoration:none" href="#" target="_blank">The longest corridor among all Hindu temples in India</a></p>
                </div>
        <!-- Slide 2 -->
        <div class='slideDiv' data-width='500' data-content='' data-link='' data-delay='5000'> <img class='stack_img' src='images/madurai.jpg' width='500' height='333' alt='' />
                  <p data-title='title' class="-90,bl,10,10" data-background-color="rgba(153,204,0, 0.6)" data-color="#ffffff">Madurai</p>
                  <p data-title='caption' class="50,250" data-background-color="rgba(153,204,0, 0.6)" data-color="#ffffff">The Temple City</p>
                </div>
        <!-- Slide 3 -->
        <div class='slideDiv' data-width='500' data-content='' data-link='FG0fTKAqZ5g' data-delay='3000'> <!-- data-link: add youtube video id here --> 
                  <img class='stack_img' src='images/mahal.jpg' width='500' height='333' alt='' />
                  <p data-title='title' class="-90,bl,10,10" data-background-color="rgba(204,0,0, 0.6)" data-color="#ffffff">Madurai</p>
                  <p data-title='caption' class="50,50" data-background-color="rgba(204,0,0, 0.6)" data-color="#ffffff">Thirumalai Nayakar Mahal</p>
                  <p data-title='caption' class="50,250" data-background-color="rgba(51,51,51, 0.6)" data-color="#ffffff">Classic fusion of Dravidian, Islamic styles</p>
                </div>
        <!-- Slide 4 -->
        <div class='slideDiv' data-width='500' data-content='' data-link='4749536' data-delay='3000'> <!-- data-link: add vimeo video id here --> 
                  <img class='stack_img' src='images/kodai.jpg' width='500' height='333' alt='' />
                  <p data-title='title' class="-90,bl,10,10" data-background-color="rgba(0,153,204, 0.6)" data-color="#ffffff">Kodaikanal</p>
                  <p data-title='caption' class="50,50" data-background-color="rgba(0,153,204, 0.6)" data-color="#ffffff">Princess of Hill stations</p>
                  <p data-title='caption' class="50,250" data-background-color="rgba(51,51,51, 0.6)" data-color="#ffffff">Kodaikanal</p>
                </div>
        <!-- Slide 5 -->
        <div class='slideDiv' data-width='500' data-content='image' data-link='' data-target='' data-delay='3000' > <img class='stack_img' src='images/kutralam.jpg' width='500' height='333' alt='' />
                  <p data-title='title' class="-90,bl,10,10" data-background-color="rgba(255,102,0, 0.6)" data-color="#ffffff">Courtallam</p>
                  <p data-title='caption' class="50,250" data-background-color="rgba(51,51,51, 0.6)" data-color="#ffffff">The Numerous Waterfalls & Cascades</p>
                </div>
        <!-- Slide 6 -->
        <div class='slideDiv' data-width='500' data-content='' data-link='' data-target='' data-delay='3000'> <img class='stack_img' src='images/ooty.jpg' width='500' height='333' alt='' />
                  <p data-title='title' class="-90,bl,10,10" data-background-color="rgba(94,73,188, 0.6)" data-color="#ffffff">Ooty</p>
                  <p data-title='caption' class="50,50" data-background-color="rgba(51,51,51, 0.6)" data-color="#ffffff">A Place you will love the Most</p>
                </div>
        <!-- Slide 7 -->
        <div class='slideDiv' data-width='500' data-content='' data-link='' data-target='' data-delay='3000'> <img class='stack_img' src='images/kany.jpg' width='500' height='333' alt='' />
                  <p data-title='title' class="-90,bl,10,10" data-background-color="rgba(4,4,4, 0.6)" data-color="#ffffff">Kanyakumari</p>
                  <p data-title='caption' class="50,200" data-background-color="rgba(128,128,128, 0.6)" data-color="#ffffff">Southernmost tip of India</p>
                  <p data-title='caption' class="50,250" data-background-color="rgba(91,91,91, 0.6)" data-color="#ffffff"><a style="text-decoration:none" href="http://www.bing.com" target="_blank">Thiruvalluvar Statue, Vivekananda Rock Memorial</a></p>
                </div>
      </div>
              <!-- /sliderHolder --> 
            </div>
    <!-- /sliderCointainer --> 

    <!-- accordion controls --> 
    <!--<div class="controls">
                <div class="controls_prev"><img src='dcodes/sliders/dream-accordion/data/icons/controls_prev.gif' width='9' height='13' alt='controls_prev'/></div>
        <div class="controls_toggle"><img src='dcodes/sliders/dream-accordion/data/icons/controls_play.gif' width='9' height='13' alt='controls_toggle'/></div>
        <div class="controls_next"><img src='dcodes/sliders/dream-accordion/data/icons/controls_next.gif' width='9' height='13' alt='controls_next'/></div>
            </div>--> 

    <!-- accordion scroll --> 
    <!--<div class="scroll">
                    <div class="scrollTrack"></div>
          <div class="scrollBar"></div>
        </div>-->
    <div class="fontMeasure">a</div>

    <!-- preloader
        <div class="mediaPreloader"></div>--> 

  </div>
          <!-- /sliderWrapper --> 
        </div>
<!-- DC Dream Accordion End -->
<div class="dc_clear"></div>
<!-- line break/clear line -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi! Could you should post some code? You're website does not seem to be available...

Comment: i have updated the coding snippet. can you pls rectify it

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting `HTTP Error 503 (Service Unavailable)` - basically the server is simply not available right now. That means some of your files are not being downloaded.

You probably want to check the server to make sure it's working properly.
To check for errors in Chrome: *right click on your page > Inspect element*